# Exiting a secondary Perl script and returning to the main program

Tags: perl

I am running a Perl script to control two other scripts. The user of the main program can call the two secondary scripts with the following line.

```
do 'Task_A.pl';
```

The script then runs **Task_A.pl** but I would like to find a way of then exiting **Task_A.pl** and return to the main program. If possible I would like to return to the function where I last called the secondary script. I am not sure as to what this is called but I appreciate any input for a possible solution.

This is the whole main program, not much to it at the moment.

```
my $selecion;

#Looping variables.
my $program_loop = 1;

while ($program_loop == 1)
{
    print "Please choose one of the programs listed in the menu.\n";

    #Program menu where the user chooses from the presented options.
    print "[1] - Script A.\n";
    print "[2] - Script B.\n";
    print "[3] - Exit program.\n";

    my $user_input = <>;

    if ($user_input == 1) # <-- Scrip_A.pl
    {
        do 'Task_A.pl';
    }
    elsif ($user_input == 2) # <-- Scrip_B.pl
    {
        do 'Task_B.pl';     
    }
    elsif ($user_input == 3) # <-- Exit Program
    {
        #The user can choose to exit from the menu.
        print "The program will now exit.\n";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Programmers don't `die`, they just `GOSUB` without `RETURN`.

Comment: I think what you actually want to do is use function calls. `do` is most likely a terrible idea. Please show some more of the actual code. It's also not clear how the user (is that a programmer) of the main script would call a secondary script.

Comment: I thought so too. Using `do` is probably not the best way to go about but I am not really sure what my options are here.

Comment: If there is no shared memory/variables necessary, start a new process. Alternatively, refactor your two programs into modules that share the same interface and use those. This will be hard if there is a lot of global legacy stuff going on. As your program does not have `use strict` and `use warnings`, I will assume that is the case. Why are you doing this exactly?

Comment: Generally speaking, you're doing something wrong if you use `do`.

Answer (score 3):

[do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) does not start another process. If that's what you want, use "[system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)()".

If you want **do**, then it's probably best to just put everything into a function in the file to be evaluated and call the function at the end of the file.

Use "**return**" to leave the function and return to next instruction after **do**.

Comment: I tried that but somehow the  **Task_A.pl** program just exits without returning to the main program.

Comment: You need to understand what `do` does. It's not a fork or a sub-process, it just slurps in the file and runs it in place. Over and over again, if you decide to do so.

Comment: Yup, haven't used do in decades :-)

Comment: I use it with BLOCKs. But not with files.

Comment: I tried using `system('Task_A.pl');` instead and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great! You may want to mark the answer as a solution then.

Comment: I think you can greatly improve the answer by formatting it a bit, linking to the perldoc for `system` and explaining why that works, with a small example. Note I have not downvoted it.